# Force hyperlinks to open target files in notepad

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a script that goes and grabs all of the documents from a certain folder and lists all of the files in that folder. It then goes and makes a link to open these files from inside of Excel. I was wondering if there was a way to put it in a shell so that the files only opened in notepad. The code that I am using right now is:

```
Sub MakeLink(ByVal cell As Range, ByVal url As String, ByVal txt As String, ByVal tooltip_text As String)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=cell, _
            Address:=url, _
            ScreenTip:=tooltip_text, _
            TextToDisplay:=txt
    End Sub

Sub Portfolios()

    Range("A1:Z200").Clear
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Range("A3").Font.Bold = True


    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Library")


     'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Portfolios")
    ws.Cells(3, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & " are:"

     'Loop through the Files collection
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 3, 2).Value = objFile.Name
        MakeLink ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 3, 2), objFile, objFile.Name, objFile.Name

    Next

     'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know I have to do something along the lines of `MakeLink = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe", 1)` but I seem to be hitting a bit of a snag as to where this will fit.

Thanks,
F

Answer (score 1):

Files will open in whatever is the default program for the file type.

If you want to force them to open in notepad then you'll have to write some code to process the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event: you can get the cell text from the Target parameter and shell out notepad from there.

To prevent problems with the hyperlink taking users elsewhere, just set the target address to the same cell as the one containing the hyperlink.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim fPath As String, res

    fPath = Target.TextToDisplay
    res = Shell("notepad.exe """ & fPath & """", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

To create the hyperlinks:

```
Sub MakeLink(rng As Range, txt As String)
    Dim addr As String

    addr = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address(False, False)
    rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=rng, Address:="", _
                     SubAddress:=addr, TextToDisplay:=txt

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm I am trying this and it is still taking the hyperlink to the program that the machine associates it to.

Comment: Did you change the Address in your hyperlinks to not point to the file, but instead back to the cell containing the link? "TextTodisplay" will need to be the full path, or you can just use the filename and add the parent folder in the event handler.

Comment: Yes I changed the target. I also tried to embed the Sub into the Portfolios sub and that didn't work either

Comment: The MakeLinks sub I posted should create links that do nothing (they just link back to themselves). The event handler then captures the path or filename and open the file directly.